# how to prevent 'tar extract' from changing the permssions for current directory?

Tags: permissions, tar

While trying to make my tarballs reproducible, i followed [this guide](http://h2.jaguarpaw.co.uk/posts/reproducible-tar/).

As a side-effect I noticed that I can easily create a tar-file that, when unpacked will change the permissions of the *current working directory* (where i extract my files into).

Like so:

```bsh
$ rm -rf /tmp/user
$ mkdir -p /tmp/user/test
$ touch /tmp/user/test/README.txt

$ ls -lhan /tmp/user/ /tmp/user/test/README.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 11002 11002    0 Sep 15 10:31 /tmp/user/test/README.txt
/tmp/user/:
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x  3 11002 11002 4.0K Sep 15 10:31 .
drwxrwxrwt 23     0     0  20K Sep 15 10:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 11002 11002 4.0K Sep 15 10:31 test
$ cd /tmp/user/test
$ tar --numeric-owner --owner=0 --group=0 --mode="go-rwx,u-w" --transform 's|\./|foobar/|' \
      -czf ../foobar.tgz .
$ tar tvf ../foobar.tgz
dr-x------ 0/0               0 2021-09-15 10:25 ./
-r-------- 0/0               0 2021-09-15 10:25 foobar/README.txt
$ cd /tmp/user/
$ tar xvf foobar.tgz
$ ls -lhan
total 40K
dr-x------  4 11002 11002 4.0K Sep 15 10:31 .
drwxrwxrwt 23     0     0  20K Sep 15 10:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 11002 11002 4.0K Sep 15 10:33 foobar
-rw-r--r--  1 11002 11002  143 Sep 15 10:32 foobar.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  2 11002 11002 4.0K Sep 15 10:31 test
$ rm foobar.tgz 
rm: cannot remove 'foobar.tgz': Permission denied
$
```

So what happens is:

- the tarfile contains a `./` entry that has permissions `0500` (aka `r-x------`)
- when extracting the tarfile it will also extract the `./` direcctory (which happens to be the current directory) and sets its permissions to the ones found in the archive
- after the operation, the user can no longer remove files from this directory and others can no longer do anything with it.

this comes as a big surprise. it might render the system "unusable" for the user (e.g. effectively running `chmod a-rwx` on the users home directory).

of course it is easy enough to restore the permissions - if you have heard of `chmod` before (something the typical Ubuntu user might not) *and* you remember the prior permissions (something I cannot say for myself and an arbitrary directory where i would extract a tarball)

so my question is twofold:

- how can i prevent `tar --extract` to change the permissions of my current working directory while still preserving the permissions of the *other* files in the archive?
- how can I prevent `tar --create` from actually creating such an archive (so that it also works for people that don't know the answer to the first question), while still prepending a known path-component)?

#### edit

i probably already found parts of the answer to my 2nd question.

Changing the path mangling to `--transform 's|^\.|foobar|'` will *also* mangle the `./` entry into `foobar/`, which will then get the permissions declared in the archive (and leave my current working directory alone).
I wonder though why `--transform 's|\./|foobar/|'` will **not** mangle `./` (as it seems this matches the `\./` regex nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I’m aware, the only way to prevent changes to `.`’s metadata when extracting a tarball is to skip existing files, with [the `--skip-old-files` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Dealing-with-Old-Files.html) available in GNU `tar`. This covers more than `.` and will result in *any* existing files being kept as-is, instead of being overwritten by the version in the tarball.

I’m not sure why your `--transform` fails. [The recommended approach to prepend a path when extracting](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/transform.html) is to “replace” the start anchor with the desired directory, *e.g.* `tar --transform 's,^,foobar/,' ...`. To avoid messing up symlinks, a suffix can be added, *e.g.* `tar --transform 's,^,foobar/,S'` which will *not* apply the transformation to symlink targets.

Comment: afaict `./` does not match because the entry in the tarfile is really `.` and flagged as a directory, and it's only the printout of `--list` that appends the trailing `/` to indicate that this entry is indeed a directory. the entry `./README.txt` does match `$./` so it is replaced correctly, whereas the directory itself `.` (disguised as `./`) matches `$.^`

Comment: @umläute that’s what I thought initially, but the raw contents of the archive do contain `./` in the corresponding entry.

Comment: another problem that i just stumbled upon is, that the transformation is *also* applied to symlink targets, so if my archive contains a symlink `./blabla/README.txt -> ../README.txt` this will by transformed to `foobar/blabla/README.txt -> foobar./README.txt` (in my transformation) resp. `foobar/./blabla/README.txt -> foobar/../README.txt` (in yours) which are both unusable. it seems i really need two transforms: `--transform 's|^\./|foobar/|' --transform 's|^\.$|foobar|'`; urgh.

Comment: @umläute the linked documentation explains how to handle symlinks; see the `S` suffix (so `--transform 's,^,foobar/,S'`).